# How can I detect NULL string or isn't NULL string

Tags: c++, queue

I want to print productCode but in a while loop but when it's over I receive error.

```
    void Queue::listProduct(Queue* _root)
    {
        Queue *iter;
        iter = _root;

        while (iter->productCode != "")

        {
            cout << iter->productCode << endl;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
    }
```

productCode is string 
first productCode="10",
second productCode="20",
.
.
.
last productCode="60"

I see 60 then I recieve error.

Comment: *productCode is string*.  That doesn't tell us what the real type `productCode` is.  Is it a `std::string`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: it is a std::string

Comment: Then the answer is easy: `std::string` can never be "null".,wo there is no need to check.

Comment: If you want to check if a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is empty, there's a very easy way. One that just about all books, tutorials and (hopefully) classes should have mentioned.

Comment: @HakanBakacak *how can I stop while loop* -- What do you mean?  Your `while` loop is supposed to stop on an empty string.  So you *are* stopping the loop.  Maybe your `Queue` class and the way you set up your data is broken, causing your loop to go off the rails?

Comment: it isn't stop and it try to read again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should not be checking if `productCode` is empty or not. It should be checking if `iter` itself is null or not.  The end of a linked list is indicated by a null pointer.

```
void Queue::listProduct(Queue* _root)
{
    Queue *iter = _root;
    while (iter)
    {
        cout << iter->productCode << endl;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

Since you are not stopping your loop correctly, you are reaching past the end of the list, that is why you crash when trying to access `productCode` for an invalid node.

Answer (score 1):

Per your question's title, to compare C-Style character arrays (strings) for null:

```
char * p_text[] = "Hello World!";
if (p_text == nullptr) // Check the pointer for null.
{
 //...
}
if (p_text[0] == '\0') // Check if string is empty.
```

Comparing `std::string` (for empty):

```
std::string productCode;
if (productCode.empty())
```

Or

```
if (productCode.length() == 0)
```

A `std::string` is not a pointer, so you shouldn't test it for `NULL` or `nullptr`.